# Securing $_SERVER variables

Tags: php, security, xss

I'm working on a massive web application that relies heavily on using $_SERVER[php_self], and $_SERVER[query string] - I know these are terrible practices, however the client only cares about it being fixed for the short term, and trust me it is massive, so I have to find a way to secure the variables. An example is the form action is php_self and a query string if it's set, so it's fairly easy to mess with the URL and have some XSS happen. So my ultra quick fix was to loop through $_GET and htmlspecialchars them, which disallowed the XSS I know (which isn't a lot) - So I was wondering what other things I could do to prevent them from being abused? Thoughts?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't you just use something along the lines of:

```
$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] = htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])
```

in some globally include()-ed file?

Or disable PATHINFO in your webserver if that's possible. As I understand it, that'll go a long way too.

Here is some more info which may be useful: http://www.mc2design.com/blog/php_self-safe-alternatives

Comment: That's what I did, well htmlspecialchars anyway.

Comment: You mentioned running htmlspecialchars() on $_GET, not on $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].

Comment: Ah, I meant all $_SERVER values. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

Is data being stored in a database?  The next most likely form of abuse is SQL injection attacks.  Converting single quotes into ' should make that substantially more difficult.

Of course that is the wrong way to fix things.  But when your house is on fire, sometimes you can't get worried about a little water damage.